# Conditional SUM() based on text of a cell using iWork

Tags: iwork, numbers

I have some basic data

```
Name | Amount
Jake | 10
Jake | 12
Jake | 13
Ben  | 1
Ben  | 14
Ali  | 9
Ali  | 4
```

I want to total up the `amount` for each person so I end up with something like

```
Jake | 35
Ben  | 15
Ali  | 13
```

Rather than specifying which cells are Jake's, Ben's and Ali's I want to do this using a function. Pseudo code might look like:

```
TOTAL = WHERE `Name` IS "Jake" IN `COL-A` + `Amount`
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It would appear that `SUMIF()` does exactly this

```
 =SUMIF(test-range, “test”, [sum-range])
```